# make text selectable inside an unselectable div

Tags: css

In my page i have made an entire div unselectable, with the help of this css (which i got from stackoverflow it self)

```
    .unselectable {
   -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   /*
     Introduced in IE 10.
     See http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/
   */
   -ms-user-select: none;
   user-select: none;
}
```

Now i got an h2 tag inside this unselectable div.And i want that h2 to become selectable.Is there any way to achieve this easly.

I have forgot some thing in my question . i got three h2 in my code an i need specific one to be selectable so i added a class to this h2 and tried some thing like this .unselectable:not(.class-of-h2) (which i got from below answers).but its not working

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use for your h2 element

```
.unselectable h2{
 -moz-user-select: text;
 -khtml-user-select: text;
 -webkit-user-select: text;
 -ms-user-select: text;
 user-select: text;
}
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Dineshkani/37TMv/)

Comment: I dont know whether this is the right answer or not ,but this thing definitely worked for me.

Comment: Yes, it seems that you can override the setting on an parent element simply that way. The [MDN page on `user-select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-user-select) is somewhat misleading: generally `none` allows override in inner elements, but Firefox has a different setup: `none` allows no overrides, `-moz-none` does.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the below **CSS**

```
.unselectable h2 {
   -moz-user-select: text;
   -khtml-user-select: auto;
   -webkit-user-select: auto ;
   -ms-user-select: auto;
   user-select: auto;
 }
```

See the **[demo](http://jsbin.com/evihuq/1/edit)**

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
     .unselectable:not(h2:nth-child(2)) {
      //your data
      }
```

**not** can exclude the element from your list of selector
this can make your whole div unselectable except h2 element.

Comment: :I have forgot some thing in  my question . i got three h2 in my code an i need specific one to be selectable so i added a class to this h2 and tried some thing like this
.unselectable:not(.class-of-h2) .but its not working